# Why does readline get stuck?

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

So here is my code, I'm trying to call a function from fetch that should begin asking the user for input, the function itself works fine alone, but when calling it from `.then` it outputs "Enter Artist Name: " and when you enter a line and hit enter, it doesn't go on.

```
function getLyrics(searchTerm) {
  let url = geniusUrl + searchTerm + '-' + 'lyrics';

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(data);
      lyrics = $('.lyrics').text().trim();
      //styling for console
      if (lyrics) {
        console.log('                    ');
        console.log('####################');
        console.log('                    ');
        console.log(lyrics);
        console.log('                    ');
        console.log('####################');
        console.log('                    ');
      } else if (!lyrics) {
        manualSearch();
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}

function manualSearch() {
  console.log('Couldn\'t Find Lyrics!');
  console.log('-----Try Manual Search-----');
  getData();
}

function getData() {
  rl.question('Enter Artist Name: ', answer1 => {
    rl.question('Enter Song Name: ', answer2 => {
      if (answer1 != '' && answer2 != '') {
        artistName = answer1.toLowerCase().trim();
        songName = answer2.toLowerCase().trim();
        searchTerm = artistName + songName;
        searchTerm = searchTerm.trim().replace(/in'/g, 'ing').replace(/\W/g, ' ').replace(/n t/g, 'nt').replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').join('-');
        getLyrics(searchTerm);
      } else {
        console.log('Not Valid');
        getData();
      }
    });
  });
  rl.close();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For some odd reason when I used `readline-sync` instead of node `readline` for the "getData" function, It worked!

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't do anything, you declare 3 functions but never call any of them. Also, `rl` is used but is never defined.

Comment: that is not all of it, I've already defined the variables and also tested the "getdata" function alone and it's working but why not with fetch!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are closing `readline` before it gets completed.

What you are doing is:

```
function getData() {
  rl.question('Enter Artist Name: ', answer1 => {
    rl.question('Enter Song Name: ', answer2 => {
      // Your logic........
    });
  });
  rl.close(); // This will close readline
}
```

And what you should do is:

```
function getData() {
  rl.question('Enter Artist Name: ', answer1 => {
    rl.question('Enter Song Name: ', answer2 => {
      // Your logic........
      rl.close(); // This will wait until two question asked.
    });
  });
}
```